# Difference with Net::SSH::Perl on perl 5.12 and 5.14

Tags: perl, ssh

I have the following code (of course I replaced myremoteserver.com):

```
use Modern::Perl;
use Net::SSH::Perl;
use Data::Dumper;

my $ssh = Net::SSH::Perl->new('myremoteserver.com', debug => 1, port => 2999);

$ssh->login('root');
print Dumper $ssh->cmd('uptime');
```

On a keyless environment, I'm running it both on perl 5.12 and 5.14.

On perl 5.12 it seems to work:

```
$ perl5.12 /tmp/sshtest.pl 
ko.local: Reading configuration data /Users/david/.ssh/config
ko.local: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
ko.local: Connecting to myremoteserver.com, port 2999.
ko.local: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
Math::BigInt: couldn't load specified math lib(s), fallback to Math::BigInt::Calc at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.12.3/Crypt/DH.pm line 6
ko.local: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 2.0.
.o.local: No compat match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
ko.local: Connection established.
ko.local: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
ko.local: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
ko.local: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
ko.local: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
ko.local: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
ko.local: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
ko.local: Host 'myremoteserver.com' is known and matches the host key.
ko.local: Computing shared secret key.
ko.local: Verifying server signature.
ko.local: Waiting for NEWKEYS message.
ko.local: Send NEWKEYS.
ko.local: Enabling encryption/MAC/compression.
ko.local: Sending request for user-authentication service.
ko.local: Service accepted: ssh-userauth.
ko.local: Trying empty user-authentication request.
ko.local: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey.
ko.local: Next method to try is publickey.
ko.local: Publickey: testing agent key '/Users/david/.ssh/github_rsa'
ko.local: Authentication methods that can continue: publickey.
ko.local: Next method to try is publickey.
Permission denied at /tmp/sshtest.pl line 9
```

But on perl 5.14:

```
$ perl5.14 /tmp/sshtest.pl 
ko.local: Reading configuration data /Users/david/.ssh/config
ko.local: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
ko.local: Connecting to myremoteserver.com, port 2999.
ko.local: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
ko.local: Net::SSH::Perl Version 1.34, protocol version 2.0.
.o.local: No compat match: OpenSSH_5.8p1 Debian-1ubuntu3
ko.local: Connection established.
ko.local: Sent key-exchange init (KEXINIT), wait response.
ko.local: Algorithms, c->s: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
ko.local: Algorithms, s->c: 3des-cbc hmac-sha1 none
ko.local: Entering Diffie-Hellman Group 1 key exchange.
ko.local: Sent DH public key, waiting for reply.
ko.local: Received host key, type 'ssh-dss'.
ko.local: Host 'myremoteserver.com' is known and matches the host key.
ko.local: Computing shared secret key.
ko.local: Verifying server signature.
Key verification failed for server host key at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.1/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 92
```

The only difference I see is Math::BigInt returns a warning on perl 5.12.

Some debugging info:

```
~ $ perl5.12 -MNet::SSH::Perl -e 'print $Net::SSH::Perl::VERSION, "\n";'
1.34
~ $ perl5.14 -MNet::SSH::Perl -e 'print $Net::SSH::Perl::VERSION, "\n";'
1.34
~ $ perl5.12 -MMath::BigInt -e 'print $Math::BigInt::VERSION, "\n";'
1.997
~ $ perl5.14 -MMath::BigInt -e 'print $Math::BigInt::VERSION, "\n";'
1.997
```

Any idea what the problem here is?

Comment: Is the client on two different machines? Based on that output they both fail. Though 5.14 fails on the host key, not your public key. Log in manually with your ssh client on the command line and it should tell you there's a line in known_hosts that doesn't match what the server sends. You can delete that line and login again and it should save the new key. Generally this happens because of an IP change.

Comment: This is the same machine, using the same environment with no keys. I forgot to point out that the problem really is not that 5.12 ends with permission denied. The real problem is that the perl 5.14 version fails with "Key verification failed for server host key at /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.14.1/Net/SSH/Perl/SSH2.pm line 92" unlike the 5.12 version o__O

Comment: Maybe an issue with Math::BigInt? Sigh.

Comment: Math::BigInt is dual-lifed, so you can upgrade it in perl5.12 to latest, and hopefully get rid of those warnings.

Comment: @damog - try removing the host key from known_hosts and recreate it by logging in again. See if that clears the problem.

Comment: @Cfreak, I completely removed everything on ~/.ssh intentionally to test. I can see that Net::SSH::Perl writes to a new ~/.ssh/known_hosts2, but that is both the case when it fails and when it succeeds.

Comment: @Ether: As I showed before, Math::BigInt's latest version is installed in both perl 5.12 and 5.14.

Comment: I think I found the issue. It is on GMP and Math::BigInt::GMP. More details soon.

Answer (score 1):

There was a change to the default value for a configuration option that controlled how https validation was performed (specifically, the `PERL_LWP_SSL_VERIFY_HOSTNAMES` environment variable), when [LWP::Protocol::https](http://metacpan.org/module/LWP%3a%3aProtocol%3a%3ahttps) was pulled out of the main LWP library - now hostname checking is on by default, where it was off previously.  It is possible that your perl 5.14 library picked up these new changes, and 5.12 is using the old versions.

There is also more information in ["Now you need LWP::Protocol::https"](http://blogs.perl.org/users/brian_d_foy/2011/07/now-you-need-lwpprotocolhttps.html).

Comment: I don't think this is related at all to LWP and SSL. I believe it's how Math::BigInt is implemented, it might not be anything at all related to SSH or even SSL.